# Writing Data Table to Google Sheets

Tags: orange

I am interested in taking a "Data Table" I have got through doing a prediction using Orange and writing this to Google Sheets. I have successfully connected to my google sheet using my Python however, I can not seem to read the local data table with Python. I'm thinking I may be over thinking this and that there may be a way to do this easier. Perhaps by somehow using the "Save As" to write it to google sheets but didn't see that under the "Save As" function. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# Print nicely
import pprint
import Orange
from Orange.data import *
#Create scope
scope =  ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds' + ' ' +'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
#create some credential using that scope and content of startup_funding.json
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('C:\\Users\\jlockwood\\Documents\\My Project-7260cd7aa35f.json',scope)
#create gspread authorize using that credential
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
#Now will can access our google sheets we call client.open on StartupName
sheet = client.open('Ranking Orange').sheet1
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
#Access all of the record inside that
pp.pprint(Orange.version.version)
pp.pprint(result)
sheet.update_cell(2,9,'2000')
```

So in short the two things I need

1. Read Data Table from Orange using Python Script
2. Write this data from Table to Google Sheet using Python Script

Comment: If you want help to work with Orange data table check this documentation https://docs.biolab.si//3/data-mining-library/tutorial/data.html

Comment: I look through the documentation and it doesn't appear to have anything about saving your data using python to Google sheets only tabs.